# c++ xml string- required white space was missing

Tags: c++, xml, string

I would like to do validate to xml string.
I create xml string in c++
The issue is that I receive the error "Required white space was missing".
and I see that the `"&#10;"` is not create the new line as needed.
can you please advice, how to do new line in c++ string that the validation will pass?

can you please give me example?

Comment: I think you should take a look at "code" you entered... And read the help about formatting.

Comment: Also, remember that in Windows a newline is actually _two_ character: Carriage return _and_ newline, i.e. the string `"\r\n"`.

Comment: can you please give me example?

Comment: Why does an XML string require particular white space?

Comment: otherwise the validation of the xml is fail

Comment: @user1986352: Than the validation is faulty. Newlines are not syntactic elements in XML (obviously it might still be more practical to work around it by including the newline than fixing it; depends on what you are doing).

Answer (score 2):

To create a literal newline in C++ you write `"\n"`.

The `"&#10;"` simply writes the entity in the string and entities below 0x20 are not allowed, so this does not substitute newline (actually it depends on the parsing library; some accept it, some don't).

The other thing is why the validation requires the newline to be present, because it **shouldn't**. Whitespace, newlines included, is either ignored or part of value in XML, but never a syntactic element. Neither XSD nor DTD allow specifying newline would be required, so standard validation tools have no way to care.

Comment: this is the xml:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<presence xmlns:mp=" http://www.motorolasolutions.com/schema/presence/pidf-extensions/v1.0"
entity="sip:car54@agency.gov">

  <tuple id="kas892n1">
    <status>
      <basic>open</basic>
    </status>
    <dm:deviceID>urn:dn:laptop1</dm:deviceID>
    <!-- timestamp of publish-->
    <timestamp>2010-07-22T20:57:29Z</timestamp>
  </tuple>


</presence>

Comment: @user1986352: Would you be so kind and include the XML in the **question** instead, please? Render it pre-formatted (indent with 4 spaces) and check whether entities render right and if they don't, replace all `&`s with `&amp;`s

Comment: after I add the \r\n it look better but still show me require white space is missing.can you advice?

Comment: @user1986352: Did I say `"\r\n"`? *No*, I said `"\n"`. Actually this has nothing to do with the platform, but with the validator. You have to use the sequence that the validator expects. It might be `\n`, `\r\n` or `\r`, the last not being likely as it is not in common use anymore. You also have to use it at the place it expects it. If it does not indicate the position, you'll have rather hard time guessing.

Comment: the issue was that I add \n as needed and then I see that I put two attribute without space between them. do now the validation pass.  thanks very mush for the assitence

Comment: @user1986352: You are looking with a stupid text editor that does not recognize lone LF as newline. Get a better text editor. See [here for more detailed explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html).